# Algorithm to find grid spaces in between two cells

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I am making a grid based game which has "line of sight" targeting. Often times a game engine would use Raycast for this but I don't want to use an engine so I am trying to "roll my own" solution.

So basically, given `P1,P2` pairs I want to find all those spaces between them (marked `X`).

I am having a big of a hard time figuring out how to do this. Somehow I have to find out which sides are closest together and use those as my starting points for "raycast". Then I guess I could take "samples" at cell-size increments and compare those with the indexes of the cells.

Unfortunately, I don't have any code yet ... I was hoping some could help with some pseudocode just to get the algorithm. I think if I could figure out how to get the start and end points for each of the pink lines then I could use that to find the orange squares.

[image]

Comment: Does your line of sight need to be so thick? Why not just trace one ray from the center of P1 to the center of P2?

Comment: @Stef yes I thought about that but what if they are completely diagonal to each other, then nothing could ever overlap

Comment: Wait, I suppose that's not true ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apparently, [Bresenham algorithm](https://deepnight.net/tutorial/bresenham-magic-raycasting-line-of-sight-pathfinding/) is a good choice here.

[image]

I wish I could post some content in addition to the link but it wouldn't help me give a complete context. So, better to visit the link and use the information there. Don't miss out on the comments section. There are good insights there as well.

2. Please check this as well [Elegant/Clean (special case) Straight-line Grid Traversal Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233522/elegant-clean-special-case-straight-line-grid-traversal-algorithm).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shridhar, that should be enough info to get me going.

Comment: The reason I had wanted to make the line thicker was because of the whole "diagonal lines can look through walls" element. But I think that can be resolved by increasing the thickness of the walls (increasing the grid size if needed to accomodate). So Bresenham algorithm should do the job.

Comment: @maxpleaner I am glad you are unblocked now.